# No route matches [GET] "/refinery"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have installed Refinery CMS using this guide:http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app.
When I go to http://0.0.0.0:3000/refinery it tells me

> No route matches [GET] "/refinery"

What do I do now?

UPD rake routes output

> ```
>            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
>               bas GET    /bas(.:format)              bas#index
>                   POST   /bas(.:format)              bas#create
>            new_ba GET    /bas/new(.:format)          bas#new
>           edit_ba GET    /bas/:id/edit(.:format)     bas#edit
>                ba GET    /bas/:id(.:format)          bas#show
>                   PATCH  /bas/:id(.:format)          bas#update
>                   PUT    /bas/:id(.:format)          bas#update
>                   DELETE /bas/:id(.:format)          bas#destroy
>             users GET    /users(.:format)            users#index
>                   POST   /users(.:format)            users#create
>          new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)        users#new
>         edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
>              user GET    /users/:id(.:format)        users#show
>                   PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
>                   PUT    /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
>                   DELETE /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
>             leads GET    /leads(.:format)            leads#index
>                   POST   /leads(.:format)            leads#create
>          new_lead GET    /leads/new(.:format)        leads#new
>         edit_lead GET    /leads/:id/edit(.:format)   leads#edit
>              lead GET    /leads/:id(.:format)        leads#show
>                   PATCH  /leads/:id(.:format)        leads#update
>                   PUT    /leads/:id(.:format)        leads#update
>                   DELETE /leads/:id(.:format)        leads#destroy
>          sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)         sessions#create
>       new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new
>           session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
>              root GET    /                           static_pages#home
>        adminadmin GET    /adminadmin(.:format)       leads#index
>                   GET    /leads(.:format)            leads#index
>            signup GET    /signup(.:format)           users#new
>               new GET    /new(.:format)              leads#new
>            signin GET    /signin(.:format)           sessions#new
>           signout DELETE /signout(.:format)          sessions#destroy
>              help GET    /help(.:format)             static_pages#help
>             about GET    /about(.:format)            static_pages#about
>           contact GET    /contact(.:format)          static_pages#contact check_lead_car_status GET
> ```
>
> /check_car_status(.:format) static_pages#check_lead_car_status
>        make_appointment mgeGET    /appointment(.:format)      static_pages#appointment
>                    mail GET    /send_email(.:format)       static_pages#ma

UPD2:
My Gemfile

```
 gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'ffaker'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.9'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'refinerycms'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this because a typo? Shouldn't you be visiting: http://localhost:3000/refinery instead? `e` rather than `a`\

EDIT: Is not a typo.

Did you run `rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation` while following the tutorial? Did your `routes.rb` file changed? It should have something like:

```
mount Refinery::Core::Engine
```

Comment: sorry a typo is here on stack oveflow question no `No route matches [GET] "/refinery"` (C)

Comment: So, how about you show us your routes? Have you restarted your server? What's the output of `rake routes`

Comment: I've updated my answer, it appears you haven't mounted Refinery

Comment: rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation - yes

Comment: Did your routes.rb file changed? - no

Comment: It should if you see the tutorial it should: "injects Refinery’s mounting line into your config/routes.rb file", so try that again and see what it changes. And let's the refocus the problem there.

Comment: Now it gives me an error `jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects/car_play$ rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation
Could not find generator refinery:cms.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102018/discussion-between-leito-and-user2950593).

Answer (score 1):

I've been working through the initial tutorial, and there is no mention of running the command  `rails generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation`. After running that command, the default users screen appears. Guess the tutorial needs to be updated.